# Magento with Nginx and Varnish - 302's, cookies, and redirects?

Tags: magento, redirect, cookies, nginx, varnish

I'm testing out Varnish to increase load times with Magento, so far caching has worked fantastic. I can serve up 32-35 pages/sec for index.php, and max out at 1200/sec for catalog pages. However I've run into a problem that I'm really struggling with. I've been trying to fix this for days now. When adding a product to the cart, it redirects to the homepage and then displays "Item XXX has been added to your cart". I can see Varnish getting the 302 to return it back to the page I added the item from, but it always bounces back to the homepage. The same problem exists when adding a product for comparison, but this never gets added to the list of items to compare.

You can see the site here:
http://test.autoracks.com

Here's my default.vcl:

```
        # default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content server.
        backend default {
          .host = "127.0.0.1";
          .port = "8080";
        }

        # admin backend with longer timeout values. Set this to the same IP & port as your default server.
        backend admin {
          .host = "127.0.0.1";
          .port = "8080";
          .first_byte_timeout = 18000s;
          .between_bytes_timeout = 18000s;
        }


        # add your Magento server IP to allow purges from the backend
        acl purge {
          "localhost";
          "127.0.0.1";
        }


        sub vcl_recv {
            if (req.restarts == 0) {
                if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
                    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
                    req.http.X-Forwarded-For ", " client.ip;
                } else {
                    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
                }
            }

            if (req.request != "GET" &&
              req.request != "HEAD" &&
              req.request != "PUT" &&
              req.request != "POST" &&
              req.request != "TRACE" &&
              req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
              req.request != "DELETE" &&
              req.request != "PURGE") {
                /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
                return (pipe);
            }

            # purge request
            if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
                    error 405 "Not allowed.";
                }
                purge("obj.http.X-Purge-Host ~ " req.http.X-Purge-Host " && obj.http.X-Purge-URL ~ " req.http.X-Purge-Regex " && obj.http.Content-Type ~ " req.http.X-Purge-Content-Type);
                error 200 "Purged.";
            }



            # switch to admin backend configuration
            if (req.http.cookie ~ "adminhtml=") {
                set req.backend = admin;
            }

            # we only deal with GET and HEAD by default    
            if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
                return (pass);
            }

            # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
            set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://[^/]+", "");

            # static files are always cacheable. remove SSL flag and cookie
            if (req.url ~ "^/(media|js|skin)/.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js|swf|ico)$") {
                unset req.http.Https;
                unset req.http.Cookie;
            }

            # not cacheable by default
            if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Https) {
                return (pass);
            }

            # do not cache any page from
            # - index files
            # - ...
            #if (req.url ~ "^/(index)") {
            #    return (pass);
            #}

            # as soon as we have a NO_CACHE cookie pass request
            if (req.http.cookie ~ "NO_CACHE=") {
                return (pass);
            }

            # normalize Aceept-Encoding header
            # http://varnish.projects.linpro.no/wiki/FAQ/Compression
            if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
                if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
                    # No point in compressing these
                    remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
                } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
                    set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
                } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
                    set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
                } else {
                    # unkown algorithm
                    remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
                }
            }

            # remove Google gclid parameters
            set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA"
            set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA&foo=bar"
            set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"&gclid=[^&]+",""); # strips when QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA" or QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA&bar=baz"

            return (lookup);
        }

        # sub vcl_pipe {
        #     # Note that only the first request to the backend will have
        #     # X-Forwarded-For set.  If you use X-Forwarded-For and want to
        #     # have it set for all requests, make sure to have:
        #     # set bereq.http.connection = "close";
        #     # here.  It is not set by default as it might break some broken web
        #     # applications, like IIS with NTLM authentication.
        #     return (pipe);
        # }
        # 
        # sub vcl_pass {
        #     return (pass);
        # }
        # 
        sub vcl_hash {
            set req.hash += req.url;
            if (req.http.host) {
                 set req.hash += req.http.host;
            } else {
                set req.hash += server.ip;
            }
            if (!(req.url ~ "^/(media|js|skin)/.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js|swf|ico)$")) {
                call design_exception;
            }
            return (hash);
        }
        # 
        # sub vcl_hit {
        #     if (!obj.cacheable) {
        #         return (pass);
        #     }
        #     return (deliver);
        # }
        # 
        # sub vcl_miss {
        #     return (fetch);
        # }

        sub vcl_fetch {
            if (beresp.status == 500) {
               set beresp.saintmode = 10s;
               restart;
            }
            set beresp.grace = 5m;

            # add ban-lurker tags to object
            set beresp.http.X-Purge-URL = req.url;
            set beresp.http.X-Purge-Host = req.http.host;

            if (beresp.status == 200 || beresp.status == 301 || beresp.status == 404) {
                if (beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "text/html" || beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "text/xml") {
                    if ((beresp.http.Set-Cookie ~ "NO_CACHE=") || (beresp.ttl < 1s)) {
                        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
                        return (pass);
                    }

                    # marker for vcl_deliver to reset Age:
                    set beresp.http.magicmarker = "1";

                    # Don't cache cookies
                    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
                } else {
                    # set default TTL value for static content
                    set beresp.ttl = 4h;
                }
                return (deliver);
            }

            return (pass);
        }

        sub vcl_deliver {
            # debug info
            if (resp.http.X-Cache-Debug) {
                if (obj.hits > 0) {
                    set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
                    set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
                } else {
                   set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
                }
                set resp.http.X-Cache-Expires = resp.http.Expires;
            } else {
                # remove Varnish/proxy header
                remove resp.http.X-Varnish;
                remove resp.http.Via;
                remove resp.http.Age;
                remove resp.http.X-Purge-URL;
                remove resp.http.X-Purge-Host;
            }

            if (resp.http.magicmarker) {
                # Remove the magic marker
                unset resp.http.magicmarker;

                set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
                set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
                set resp.http.Expires = "Mon, 31 Mar 2008 10:00:00 GMT";
                set resp.http.Age = "0";
            }
        }

        # sub vcl_error {
        #     set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
        #     synthetic {"
        # <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        # <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        #  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        # <html>
        #   <head>
        #     <title>"} obj.status " " obj.response {"</title>
        #   </head>
        #   <body>
        #     <h1>Error "} obj.status " " obj.response {"</h1>
        #     <p>"} obj.response {"</p>
        #     <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
        #     <p>XID: "} req.xid {"</p>
        #     <hr>
        #     <p>Varnish cache server</p>
        #   </body>
        # </html>
        # "};
        #     return (deliver);
        # }

        sub design_exception {
        }
```

I should that if I put nginx in front everything works correctly.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, I really want to get this working!

Thanks...

Comment: Are you using the Phoenix plugin to control caching sections?

Comment: Also, the domain you mentioned - http://test.autoracks.com/ - does not have an X-Cache header in the http response... are you sure that Varnish is actually running against this domain?

Comment: Yes I am using the Phoenix extension, the X headers weren't appearing because they were off, you'll see them now. I've setup everything properly, I can see it working (very well in fact), but I'm just dealing with these 2 small details, which are kind of big. If you add a product on the product page this problem doesn't happen, but adding from the catalog/category view triggers this problem....I can't figure out why it behaves differently?

I've also tried this without the Phoenix extension and the same problem exists. It only happens when Varnish is in front passing requests to Nginx....?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is located in the Magento Core. As the method `getCurrentUrl` builds the URL using the Nginx port number (not often 80 when behind Varnish). Later when the redirect URL is decoded it fails as an "internal URL" due to the port number.

The solution (whithout modifying the Magento core) is to set Nginx to listen to port 80 and Varnish to something else. Then map incoming traffic to Varnish using iptables.

I've covered this in a blog post on [Keeping Magento satisfied behind Varnish](http://erikeng.se/post/magento-behind-varnish.html).

Answer (score 1):

when i was testing varnish with a local apache server using siege the test would sometimes send a different response url than i was expecting from the test. 
i have no idea why i never witnessed (with my eyes) a wrong page loading even though i ran it with the same vcl all the time i was developing other things. 
but i followed the advice on the on the varnish site and installed a 64 bit os.
my problems disappeared.
were you using a 32 bit system?